# Set index Home page instead of Azures This mobile app is up and running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

all my redirections in Route.Config is working fine, instead of my home default link is displaying Azure's This mobile app is up and running

> http://localhost:51540/

Bellow is my RouteConfig code

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("");



            routes.MapRoute(
    name: "/Index",
    url: "Index/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I add my code without /index i get 404 on > http://localhost:51540/ and on > http://localhost:51540/Index.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "without /index",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Does anybody know where can I change this configurations/settings?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the .UseDefaultConfiguration() method invoked in the Startup.MobileApp.cs. The part of that is the AddMobileAppHomeController() which depends on the corresponding Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Controllers.HomeController reference. I believe it is what blocks you from the implementation of what you are doing.

[Helpful post and announcement about that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to erase new MobileAppTableConfiguration() method. Works like a charms.